# Область применения Си и Си++

Tags: c++, c

Хотелось бы узнать каковы области применения языков Си и Си++ и для каких платформ чаще их используют?

Comment: Си - практически для любой мыслимой и не мыслимой платформы. Плюсы - немножко уже.

Comment: @KoVadim, не могли бы вы ответить более развернуто? Вопрос, ведь, на самом деле, довольно интересный, как для начинающих, так и для бывалых программистов не имеющих серьезного опыта программирования на C/C++.

Comment: ох, развернуто.

Начнем с того, что практически для любой создаваемой платформы нужен компилятор. и так сложилось исторически, что это вначале ассемблер, а потом Си. А имея в запасе Си, можно творить много, потому что на нам написано много библиотек и процесс идет быстрее. То же ядро Линукса написано на Си.

Второй, большой плюс Си - предсказуемость. То есть, код, который будет в результате, можно предсказать.

А вот плюсы используют там, где нужен более высокоуровневый код. Но во многих случаях можно использовать любой язык.

Comment: @KoVadim, досадно, я ожидал хоть какой-то определенности в ответе, но, в итоге, получил еще больше неопределенности...

Особенно "о многих случаях можно использовать любой язык", да, это так, но причем тут "Область применения Си и Си++"? :)

Comment: А что Вы хотели услышать?

> "о многих случаях можно использовать любой язык"

имеется ввиду, что области применения си и плюсов пересекаются.

Comment: по-мойму проще сказать где не используются C и C++ ...

так сказать пойти от обратного :)

Comment: var X = 'что-то...';

@KoVadim, хотел услышать простой ответ из разряда - вот мы например делали X и в реализации X нам очень помогло X в С || C++, использование java, C#, python и т.п. не подходило, потому-что ...

Comment: Вот именно. Но нужно узнать, что хочет человек. Может ему нужно дать ответ на экзаменационный билет.

Comment: @KoVadim, причем тут "vs"? Меня интересует реальный опыт (в т.ч. ваш), а не абстрактные фразы, просто для того, что-бы написать то, что написали вы, вообще не нужно знать C/C++, что, как-бы, намекает на то, что он, мягко говоря, не очень :)

Comment: @AlexWindHope, дмаю, реальный опыт здесь присутствующих мало что даст, так как не перекроет и части областей применения C. Я бы даже смело обобщил: областей, где сейчас не используются C или C++ просто нет.

Comment: @klopp, неужели внутри браузеров появился интерпретатор (или компилятор в native) Си с выходом на системные вызовы клиентской ОС?

Comment: @avp, ну вот, например, у меня куча всего на голом перле пишется. А библиотеки его на чём? И для XS приходится писать. Я об этом :)

Comment: @klopp, ну это здорово опосредованное программирование на Си. Вы бы еще ядро и начинку сетевого оборудования вспомнили. Тоже ведь используется.

Comment: @avp, угу, а я PHP знаю. Значит я сишник %)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Эти языки используются там, где нужно максимальное быстродействие, экономия памяти и "близость" к железу. Особенно это относится к Си. С++ уровнем чуть повыше и у программ на нем требования к ресурсам чуть больше.

Comment: Ага

    C -- макроассемблер, который считает себя языком высокого уровня.
    C++ -- расширенный макроассемблер, который считает себя языком высокого уровня...

Answer (score 7):

1. Для очень серьезных проектов, разработка и использование которых ведется несколько лет.
2. Для проектов которые используют собственные протоколы, форматы, модели и иные формы взаимодействия данных.
3. Для решений, требующих высокого уровеня надежности. Когда каждый "байт" находится под контролем.
4. Для решений, требующих высокой производительности.
5. При отсутствии готовых открытых или закрытых движков в той или иной области разработки, или неудовлетворение ими.
6. Для изучения фундаментальных основ императивного программирования.
7. Для разработки в среде поддерживающей только данные языки.(например игровые приставки)
8. Для проектов срок жизни которых должен превышать 10 лет, и следовательно требуется надежный язык разработки, который точно будет актуален в будущем.(например физический движок physx который пережил несколько крупных рефакторингов. Первоначально он не был столь популярен из-за особых требований к производительности для того времени, однако разработчики были уверены,  что в будущем он будет актуальным для массового применения, в случаи роста производительности)

В общем почти в любом крупном проекте центральное логическое ядро программного комплекса будет функционировать на одном из этих языков.

Часто:
- сети. протоколы.
- серверная сторона различных служб.
- игры.
- прикладной интерфейс для работы с аппаратными устройствами.
- любые требовательные к производительности компоненты.

Пример:

Видеоплеер(медиа проигрыватель).

Кнопки, обработки событий, настройки  - всё это можно создать используя обычный высокоуровневый язык.

А вот если нужно подгрузить содержимое видеофайла частями, потом быстро добавить в видео эффекты, перекодировать в другой формат, и воспроизвести на экран, то придется использовать Си.

С++ вроде бы есть, но встретить библиотеку, которая основана на STD-STL, большая удача. Везде говорят "написано на С++", а на деле Си с добавкой пары классов.

Comment: 1.Думаю, это не показатель, практически на любом языке можно несколько лет писать серьезный проект и долго потом его использовать.

3.Из необходимости контроля над каждым байтом не следует высокая надежность системы. Скорее, для того чтобы обеспечить высокую надежность, нужен высокий профессионализм программиста.

Comment: 1. На счёт "практически на любом" не согласен. 
Если язык широко поддерживается заинтересованной общественностью или крупной коммерческой корпорацией, тогда да в нем можно быть уверенным. 

Язык D. Поначалу столько шуму наделал: "Замена С++!". Но реальную проверку временем не выдержал. 
Новость 1 марта 2013г. на сайте http://dlang.ru/
"Всем нам интересен этот язык по определению - иначе бы нас здесь не было. И мы..."

А как можно планировать серьезный проект, если нет уверенности в том, что в windows 2020 будет присутствовать среда разработки под этот язык? Оставаться в 2020 году на windows 7

Comment: На мой взгляд — наоборот, необходимость тратить своё внимание на каждый байт означает _меньшую_ надёжность системы. Системы, которые и без явного вмешательства программиста "делают всё правильно", надёжнее.

Comment: @manking А windows 2020 будет?

Comment: @alexlz 
Должен быть. Шанс на то что он выйдет, а некая среда разработки нет, очень большой.

Вот если у вас стоит задача начать разработку достаточно масштабной системы, срок жизни которой должен составить 15 лет, то вы какой язык предпочтете? В общем и целом без придирки к мелким деталям.

Comment: @manking Задачи создавать систему на 15 лет предо мной не стоит (1). За 15 лет "либо шах, либо ишак..." (2). О том, что будет с отраслью через 15 лет не знает никто, а операционка без поддержки разработчика -- кому это надо? ms dos жива благодаря системе образования (что является нехорошим для образования знаком -- студенты изучают всякие уродства типа TSR). Так что "кому должен быть win2020?" Мне он этого не должен. А насчёт языков -- они более-менее соотносятся к какой-то области применения. Так что в тех областях, где сейчас главенствуют C++/java/C# мне более больше нравится haskell

Comment: Отрасль стабильна. Надежда на какие либо кардинальные изменения в ней очень маленькая.
Сложность разработки повышается, поэтому на рынке остаются одни и те же.

Долгоживущие проекты на чём написаны?
В 85% случаев на Си/Cи++.

- photoshop и другие adobы.
- браузеры.
- медиа плееры (mpc gom)
- антивирусы
- архиваторы win rar
- cd rw nero, alc-120, daemon
- icq
- webmoney
- текстовые редакторы 
- конвертеры форматов
и каждая третья программа.

Но я как бы привожу примеры настольных приложений. Может быть в корпоративном секторе всё наоборот.

Comment: @manking Читал статистику десятилетней давности. Лидер по научно-техническим приложениям -- C++, по бизнес-приложениям -- java. Но вот утверждение "отрасль стабильна" -- это чересчур смело. Экономика становится нестабильной, и перекормленные деньгами IT не могут быть стабильными. Правильнее, вероятно, "отрасль пока стабильна". Но это пока -- ненадолго. Ситуация сейчас меняется очень быстро. Один Кипр чего стоит.

Answer (score 0):

1. с++ компилятор есть на всех популярных платформах, а также найдется и `ide` к нему
2. c++ используется везде где только это возможно (на нем можно даже писать `cgi`-скрипты для веб)
3. с++ был признан заменить язык `assembler` и был запланирован на 100 лет работы с ним
4. его часто используют в коммерческих проектах тк у него самое высокое быстродействие

А вообще считаю в системной области программирования равных этому языку мало конкурентов

ps: язык с++ постоянно развивается, а это уже огромный плюс

Comment: А теперь все то же, только без ++

Comment: согласен можно и си но вот только зачем тогда создавали ++. я вот почему то считаю что сделали это для удобства сопровождения кода

Comment: Примерно так.

Comment: @perfect см. фальшивое первоапрельское интервью Страуструпа.

Comment: @perfect, а Вы не задумывалиь, почему Линукс написан на Си, а не на С++?

Comment: если так рассуждать то зачем на linux ставят компиляторы с++

Comment: @perfect 
С++ не призван заменить ассемблер, это задача Си.

С++ же может применяться в случаях, когда определенные части приложения требуют высокой производительности.
То есть в общем и целом, приложение состоит из высокоуровневых конструкций(собственных классов), которые очень подходят для быстрой и удобной разработки. Но если где то производительность "садится"(узкие места), то С++, как универсальный язык, позволяет это исправить, предоставляя нижний уровень Cи и даже asm.

Comment: и так можно сказать. я за что купил за то и продаю

Comment: @perfect

       если так рассуждать то зачем на linux ставят компиляторы с++

Вероятно за тем же, зачем и в других системах.

По ответу:

1. x51 -- платформа популярная. C++ там не видел.

2. CGI-скрипты можно писать даже на cmd.exe

3. Уже отвечали.

4. Бенчмарки можете предъявить?

Comment: цитата из самоучителя С++.

НУЖНО ЛИ ИЗУЧИТЬ СНАЧАЛА ЯЗЫК С?

У многих возникает вопрос: "Поскольку С++" является продолжением языка С,возможно, с начала необходимо осваивать С?" Страуструп и большинство других программистов, использующих язык С++, считают, что лучше этого не делать.

Язык С основан на концепции структурного программирования, а С++ является полностью объектно-ориентированном. Это серьезная ошибка - изучить сначала С, чтобы потом переучиваться, искореняя "вредные привычки", приобретенные при работе с языком С.

Джесс Либерти, Бредли Джонс с которыми я вполне согласен

Comment: О, горе мне! Я приступил к С++ после нескольких лет программирования на Си!

Comment: Хе-хе, а у меня до плюсов были фортран, ассемблер, бейсики и C. Всё, трындец.
Фигня всё это. Конечно, специально учить C для освоения плюсов не надо :) Но чем с большим количеством языков знаком программист, тем лучше, и тем быстрей он осваивает новые, IMHO, это очевидно.

Comment: C++ язык сложный. (Кстати, @perfect, думаю именно поэтому Linux и пишут на Си, а не только из-за нелюбви (как говорят) Линуса к С++).

Чем больше человек писал на Си до знакомства с С++, тем меньше у него желания (и потребности) запоминать   все  С++-ные заморочки.

--

Видимо достаточно остро чувствуя это, адепты С++ и не рекомендуют сначала хорошенько освоить Си, а уж потом "искоренять вредные привычки", которые частенько оказываются просто эффективными приемами программирования, только недоступными слабоподготовленной массе программистов, поступающих на работу в корпорации.

Comment: @mikillskegg Этот грех Вам уже не искупить. А уж про Бейсик ещё Дейкстра писал (или про фортран?). Вывод: Вы -- безнадёжны.

Comment: @alexlz, ой, ой, и бейсик, и фортран тоже есть в моем списке грехов!

Comment: @mikillskegg увы нам (начинал тоже -- с ассемблера для одной старой архитектуры и фортрана-2). Хотя, говорят, можно избавиться от проклятия, нарисовав в UML диаграмму классов для "HelloWorld!" (не менее 50 классов) или составив слово "вечность" из букв "о", "а", "ж", "п"...

Answer (score 0):

Парни! Вы забыли про [D Language](http://dlang.org)! Да, средств разработки адекватных для него мало, но он клевый. Компилит все в нативный код, позволяет писать ПО кросс-платформенно, имеет весьма приятный и простой синтаксис. Позволяет управлять памятью вручную, или автоматически(есть свой сборщик мусора).

Последнее время пытаюсь в свободное время познакомиться с этим языком поближе. Пока что он мне нравится.

ps:// си, си++ сейчас нужно использовать при написании драйверов, каких-то низкоуровневых программ, да приложений, в которых нужна максимальная производительность(читай игры, и иже с ними). Для веба, десктопа использовать можно, но в настоящее время, когда активно развиты и развиваются скриптовые языки, и языки типа C#, java, смысла в этих областях с++ особо то и нет - Дороже выйдет. Во-первых, потому что разработка на си/си++ сложнее, а потом спустя несколько лет поддержки этот ваш проект превратится в какашку, которую будет дешевле переписать.

**Не идите на поводу у всех, имейте свое мнение**! Попробуйте эти языки сами, и решите, нужно-ли оно вам, или нет. Пробуйте альтернативные языки, компилируемые в нативный код, сравнивайте удобство в использовании языков. **Не бойтесь экспериментировать**!

Comment: Про D не забыли, упоминался.

>Не бойтесь экспериментировать!

Многих, кто только начинает, интересует этот вопрос. Потому что нужно овладеть самой передовой технологией и/или самым крутым языком. При этом как научиться программировать их не волнует совершенно, а времени очень мало, надо побыстрей и пробовать некогда :)

Answer (score 0):

**Для программирования железа**